# Django - Changing widget on GET request according to a choice field

Tags: django, forms, model, widget

I want to change field widget to readonly if the choice of another form is 'YES'. This code is working fine to initiate widget state do readonly:

**Form:**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(AccountUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['year'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = u'readonly'
```

But how to do it according to a choice field on GET request?

**Model:**

```
class AccountUpdate(models.Model):    
    updateaddress = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=OPTION_CHOICES, default='N')
    address = models.CharField('Your address?', max_length=50)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

**Choices:**

```
OPTION_CHOICES = (  
    ('S', 'Yes'),  
    ('N', 'No'), 
)
```

Comment: why do you want to do that from the backend, just use javascript to disable the text field

Comment: do you know how could I manage a javascript function to do that? I don't want to disable them, just turn into readonly field..

Comment: Using jquery, once the selection changes, just disable the fields, and  make the css for that field look like plain text. That is the easiest work around